# How do I get the user info of a twitter user using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Using jquery's $.ajax function, I'm not able to parse the results.  For example, I used it like this

```
$.ajax({

    url : "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=techcrunch",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data)
    {
        // parse the JSON here
    },
    error : function()
    {
        alert("Failure!");
    },

});
```

This doesn't work.  Do I need a callback function?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What result do you get and what result do you expect to get?

Comment: sorry, should've been more clear.  If I just execute the URL in the browser, http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=techcrunch, I get back the JSON data.  But with the above code, I don't get any data back - Firebug shows nothing in the response.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As metnioned, this is due to the Same Origin Policy. To get around this, you should set your datatype to `jsonp`.

```
$.ajax({

    url : "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=techcrunch",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function()
    {
        alert("Failure!");
    },

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/bpnbj/

Comment: Awesome, that worked.  I didn't know what JSONP is, thank you.

Comment: this wont handle the error situation when an error occurs. jquery cannot handle jsonp error situation , it simply hides it !!  see the below fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/zrvPy

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an ajax call to an external url due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can see more info in *[Call external url through $.ajax in wordpres theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544522/call-external-url-through-ajax-in-wordpres-theme)* thread.