# How to call external url in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain-policy

I am trying to put comments on Facebook wall using jquery.

But my ajax call not alowing external url .

can anyone explain how can we use external url with jquery ?

below is my code :

```
var fbUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/16453004404_481759124404/comments?access_token=my_token";

$.ajax({        
    url: fbURL ,
    data: "message="+commentdata,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp);
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert('Error: '+e);
    }  
});
```

its giving xmlhtttprequest error.

Comment: You're getting that error because the URL fails the "Same origin policy", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All of these answers are wrong!

Like I said in my comment, the reason you're getting that error because the URL fails the "[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)", but you can still us the AJAX function to hit another domain, see [Nick Cravers answer on this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873636/no-response-from-mediawiki-api-using-jquery):

> You need to trigger JSONP behavior
>   with $.getJSON() by adding &callback=?
>   on the querystring, like this:
>
> ```
> $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles="+title+"&format=json&callback=?",
> function(data) {
>     doSomethingWith(data); 
> });
> ```
>
> You can test it here.
>
> Without using JSONP you're hitting the
>   same-origin policy which is blocking
>   the XmlHttpRequest from getting any
>   data back.

With this in mind, the follow code should work:

```
var fbURL="https://graph.facebook.com/16453004404_481759124404/comments?access_token=my_token";

$.ajax({
    url: fbURL+"&callback=?",
    data: "message="+commentdata,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Error: '+e);
    }  
});
```

Comment: $.getJSON used for getting date.here i want to post data on wall

Comment: The error callback takes three parameters (not sure if that's the right term), the first is the XHR, the second is textStatusand the third is errorThrown, can you alert these and tell us what they say?

Comment: Because it answered the original authors question?

Answer (score 7):

JQuery and PHP

In PHP file "contenido.php":

```
<?php
$mURL = $_GET['url'];

echo file_get_contents($mURL);
?>
```

In html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getContent(pUrl, pDivDestino){
        var mDivDestino = $('#'+pDivDestino);

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'contenido.php',
            dataType : 'html',
            data: {
                url : pUrl
            },
            success : function(data){                                               
                mDivDestino.html(data);
            }   
        });
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getContent('http://www.google.com/', 'contenido')">Get Google</a>
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

Comment: I have edited your answer to remove your signature. Please see the faq regarding signatures and taglines. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 3):

it is [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) problem. Common modern browsers doesn't  allow to send request to another url.

Comment: You mean 'same origin policy'.

Comment: @Andrei Andrushkevich, Correct !
So do you have any way-out or work-around for this ?
I mean, if specifically another URL is to be called, what should one do ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way is by using internel PHP code like MANOJ and Fernando suggest.

curl post/get in php file on your server --> call this php file with ajax

The PHP file let say (fb.php):

```
$commentdata=$_GET['commentdata'];
$fbUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/16453004404_481759124404/comments?access_token=my_token";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fbUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// POST data here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "message=".$commentdata);

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $server_output;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Than use AJAX GET to

```
fb.php?commentmeta=your comment goes here
```

from your server.

Or do this with simple HTML and JavaScript from externel server:

```
Message: <input type="text" id="message">
<input type="submit" onclick='PostMessage()'>
<script>
function PostMessage() {
var comment = document.getElementById('message').value;
    window.location.assign('http://yourdomain.tld/fb.php?commentmeta='+comment)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

google the javascript same origin policy

in a nutshell, the url you are trying to use must have the same root and protocol. 
so 
http://yoursite.com
cannot access
https://yoursite.com or 
http://anothersite.com

is you absolutely MUST bypass this protection (which is at the browser level, as galimy pointed out), consider the ProxyPass module for your favorite web server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi url should be calling a function which in return will give response

```
$.ajax({
url:'function to call url',
...
...

});
```

try using/calling API facebook method

Comment: the url is not the issue here, The same origin policy is to be bypassed.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below simple steps you will able to get the result

Step 1- Create one internal function **getDetailFromExternal** in your back end.
step 2- In that function call the external url by using cUrl like below function

```
 function getDetailFromExternal($p1,$p2) {

        $url = "http://request url with parameters";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true            
        ));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;
        exit;
    }
```

Step 3- Call that internal function from your front end by using javascript/jquery Ajax.