# jQuery Mobile HTTPS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ssl, https

I'm building native web app with jquery mobile and phonegap. Data is loaded from external server. Now data must be loaded using ssl, but I'm getting error:

> NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

I tried Chrome REST client and eveerything works just fine.

Code:

```
WebService.prototype.execute = function (url, params) {
    var result = {
        HttpResponseObject : {},

        onSuccess : function (data) {       
            result.HttpResponseObject.response = JSON.parse(data);
        },

        onError : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {          
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();          

            // TODO some logging for errors
            console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));       
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url:            url,
        type:           'POST',
        async:          false,
        data:           JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType:       'text',
        contentType:    'application/json',
        error:          result.onError,
        success:        result.onSuccess
    });

    return result;
};
```

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/9dBHrAGW](http://pastebin.com/9dBHrAGW)

Comment: It is better to post your code here on SA.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in order to use ajax to query an external API...

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=[myAPIKey]&q=" + movie.title + "&page_limit=1",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (msg) {
            ...awesome code here
        }});
```

The key here is the "crossDomain: true" line (maybe the dataType: 'jsonp' for some services too).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you - ajax calls are not working on external urls, but there is a way around that:

[How to call external url in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613310/how-to-call-external-url-in-jquery)

Comment: **Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.** Still not working. Giving same error.

Comment: You might have to set async to true as async false does not work for cross-domain requests.