# How to call the box apis with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, box

I am trying to integrate the box api to list out my files and folders, I am following the box documentation http://developers.box.com/oauth/. I am not able to use this with jquery style.

Can anyone please provide me a hint on how to do this using jquery/ajax ways.

All comments are most welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to integrate the API in? You will run into the **Same origin policy**, a security standard by common browsers (Chrome, Firefox, ...) if you make requests from the *client-side* of a webpage.

That said,

- the API either has to support JSONP or CORS (which should be documented somewhere) and you have to adapt your requests respectively
- or fire the requests from *your* Server-side, which would not be JQuery/ajax, but PHP (e.g. [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613310/how-to-call-external-url-in-jquery#11746758)) or any other Server script

Answer (score 1):

From the official solution for Javascript API-Requests https://developers.blog.box.com/2011/09/28/using-the-box-api-with-javascript/:

> Unless you’re lucky enough to be a Box developer like myself, you’ll be hosting your app on a domain other than box.net (or a subdomain thereof). As a result, the Javascript Same Origin Policy is going to prevent us from making Ajax requests to the API from another domain (like localhost, which we’ll be using in this tutorial).

In the tutorial there's this snippet:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.net%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Frest%3Faction%3Dget_ticket%26api_key%3D" + window.api_key + "'&amp;format=json&amp;diagnostics=true",
    function(response) {
        window.ticket = response.query.results.response.ticket;
        window.location.href = 'https://m.box.net/api/1.0/auth/' + ticket;
});
```

---

It should be easy to make it a working Javascript API:

```
function box_api_request(url, api_key, callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'" + encodeURI(url) + "%26api_key%3D" + api_key + "'&amp;format=json&amp;diagnostics=true", callback);
}

box_api_request('https://www.box.net/api/1.0/rest?action=get_ticket', '1234MY_API_KEY123', function(response) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```