# Ajax doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with ajax method. I have a form with two fields, email and password. When I use the label "a" with id = registroAction, I call the ajax method and jump somewhere else.

My code:

```
<form id="form-registro" class="margen-left-445 absoluto margen-top-40 azul-corporativo">
        <p class="bg-success espaciointerior-10 mensaje_activacion" style="display:none"></p>
        <p class="bg-danger espaciointerior-10 mensaje_activacion" style="display:none"></p>
        <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #044E7C;">Registrate gratis</h3>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="email" class="input-generico margen-top-10 margen-bottom-5" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" id="password" class="input-generico margen-top-10 margen-bottom-5" placeholder="Contraseña" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">           
        </div>
        <div class="input-group margen-bottom-20">
            <input type="password" class="input-generico margen-top-10 margen-bottom-5" placeholder="Repita contraseña" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        </div>
        <a id="registroAction" class="btn boton-generico margen-left-38">Crear una cuenta gratis</a>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" class="btn boton-generico">Cancelar</a>
    </form>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#registroAction").on("click", function(e){
        $.ajax({            
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>frontend/registro/registrarAction',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',  
            data: {email: $('#email').val(), password: $('#password').val()},
            success: function (response) {                   
                if ( response.ok == 'ok' ){
                    // Establecemos la clase necesario para mostrar el mensaje
                    var classname = ( response.ok == 'ok' ) ? '.bg-success' : '.bg-danger';
                    // Ocultamos el resto de mensajes de activacion
                    $('.mensaje_activacion').hide().html('');
                    // Mostramos y rellenamos según si ha salido bien o mal
                    $('.mensaje_activacion' + classname).html(response.responseText).show().fadeOut( 3000 );

                } else {
                    $(location).attr('href',response.url);
                }
            },
            error: function(estado){
                console.log(estado)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How does it not work? Any error messages? We can't look through a magic ball and know what you want.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`...

Comment: @War10ck Why? It doesn't have a `href` so it's not going to do anything by default.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That depends on how the page is being rendered. An `<a>` tag without an `href` is valid for HTML5 but not for previous HTML specifications. Depending on how the OP has setup his page for rendering, it either becomes a placeholder link with respect to HTML5 or it is invalid markup resulting in the unwanted navigation. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292343/is-an-anchor-tag-without-the-href-attribute-safe#answer-19167175)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your  tag should have an href attribute. You can use href="#".
Regarding your issue, you need to tell the browser to ignore the default behavior (following links):

```
$("#registroAction").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ....
}
```

This should work and prevent the weird behavior you are seeing!

Answer (score -1):

This is because of same orgin policy or your url may have redirection in server side. Refer this [How to call external url in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613310/how-to-call-external-url-in-jquery)

Comment: `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` - There doesn't seem to be any evidence of crossing origins...