# JavaScript: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I work on a `JavaScript` app that opens in the localhost address of `https://localhost:63342/WalletClient/index.html_ijt=k4ock08pqsve8hb7b2b34ou3h5`. It looks like this,

[image]

When I click the balance button, it should execute the following `Ajax GET` request and tries to open a new page `balance.html`,

```
  $("#balance").click(function () {

        address = $('#address option:selected').text().trim();
        selectedCurrency = $('#selectCurrency option:selected').text().trim();

        // make sure in the backend the currency name samll/capital doesnt matter
        $.ajax({

            url: "https://www.hostdomain.com" + "/rest/wallet/addressAndCurrency" + "/" + selectedCurrency + "/" + address,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var id = data["id"];
                window.open("/WalletClient/balance.html?walletId=" + id);
            },

            failure: function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg.toString())
            }
        });
    });
```

However, in the console, I get the message of `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and it seems that it tries to receive the `GET` request from the URL of `:63342/WalletClient/https://www.hostdomain.com/rest/wallet/addressAndCurrency/Bitcoin/mnV3CR6435p1LKcbGa8GVwt9euWrf3wWEX`

The Java app I worked is not deployed and hence, it won't be able to provide any responses. However, my concern is the `GET` request should try to receive the `JSON` from the URL of `https://www.hostdomain.com/rest/wallet/addressAndCurrency/Bitcoin/mnV3CR6435p1LKcbGa8GVwt9euWrf3wWEX` which is not trying to do.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Should be fine... Are there global ajax modifiers like ajaxPrefilters or ajaxSend?

Comment: No, it's very simple code. Do you think the code seems Ok?

Comment: I think If the url is not on the same domain, it won't work:

Comment: Please try to cut done your question to keep only the relevant parts... We don't need to see your interfact to fix an ajax issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: @Artin, I have tested the code you provided and it works fine. So the problem is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: How do you manage to test the code and which platform?

Comment: Cross-domain policies do not cause 404 errors

Comment: tested it right here on stackoverflow snippet...

Comment: Check some solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613640/3840929