# Ajax POST request from Chrome extension to django fails with 400

Tags: django, nginx, google-chrome-extension, gunicorn

I have a Django REST API running on Nginx + Gunicorn on my server (an AWS instance) and I'm trying to call this API from a Chrome extension using Ajax. I can't make it work. The API itself seems to work fine – *I can make a similar request with cURL and it works fine*. However, when I try to do it from the extension, I'm getting `400` error. There is no authentication at the moment, both the website from which I'm calling and the Django app run on https (at first I thought this might be a problem), I added both of them to `permissions` in `manifest.json`. My call (from `background.js`) looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    url: 'https://**************/',
    data: JSON.stringify(collectedData),
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        collectedData = [];
        server_response = xhr.status;
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        server_response = xhr.status;
    },
    dataType: "json"
}).always(function(){
    sendResponse({ status: server_response });
});
```

I'm running out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the view receiving the post data marked as `@csrf_exempt`? Otherwise you will have to post the `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. Maybe also a [same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613640/1011272) issue? Not sure...

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(error);` in the error callback of your request?

Comment: @VitorFreitas Can you elaborate a bit on `@csrf_exempt` and `csrfmiddlewaretoken`? I'm not doing it, but also not sure how I could use it. @YPCrumble it's just "Bad request"